# Proof that Sargan test statistic is distributed $\chi^2$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, instrumental-variables

Assume that

$$\textbf{y} = X\boldsymbol\beta + \boldsymbol\varepsilon $$

, where $\boldsymbol\varepsilon$ is an $n \times 1$ random vector and that X is an $n \times k$ matrix of regressors; $m$ of these regressors are endogenous. Let $Z$ be an $n \times (k-m+l)$ matrix where the endogenous regressors are replaced by exogenous instruments. If $\boldsymbol\beta$ is estimated by 2SLS

$$ \hat{\boldsymbol\beta}_{2SLS} = \left(X^\prime P_Z X \right)^{-1} X^\prime P_Z \textbf{y}$$
$$ P_Z= Z\left(Z^\prime  Z \right)^{-1} Z^\prime $$

, it is (supposedly) possible to show that if $E[\boldsymbol{z}_i^\prime\varepsilon_i]=\textbf{0} $, then

$$ n\frac{\hat{\boldsymbol\varepsilon}^\prime P_Z \hat{\boldsymbol\varepsilon}}{\hat{\boldsymbol\varepsilon}^\prime \hat{\boldsymbol\varepsilon}} \sim \chi^2 \left(l-m \right)$$

See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargan%E2%80%93Hansen_test . **I have not been able to find an explanation of how it is possible to show this**. That is, I have not found one that I am able to understand; see, e.g., http://www.jstor.org/stable/1907619 for the original article. My guess is that we would invoke the Central Limit Theorem

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt n} Z^\prime  \hat{\boldsymbol\varepsilon} \sim N(0,\Omega) $$

and assume that $\Omega$ is invertible, such that

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \Omega^{-\frac{1}{2}} Z^\prime  \hat{\boldsymbol\varepsilon} \sim N(0,I) $$

Then

$$ \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \Omega^{-\frac{1}{2}} Z^\prime  \hat{\boldsymbol\varepsilon} \right)^\prime \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \Omega^{-\frac{1}{2}} Z^\prime  \hat{\boldsymbol\varepsilon} \right) \sim \chi^2 (l-m) $$

, since it is a sum of independent squares. Assuming homoskedasticity, we can replace $ \Omega $ by

$$ \hat{\Omega} = \frac{\sigma^2_{\hat{\varepsilon}}}{n} Z^\prime Z$$

, which yields the Sargan test statistic.

**My question is if this proof is correct?** **Also, how can we show that the degrees of freedom are $l-m$**? The $l$-part makes sense, since all except $l$ elements of $Z^\prime \hat{\boldsymbol\varepsilon} $ are 0 by construction. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "since all except $l$ elements of $Z′\hat{\epsilon}$ are 0 by construction"? There are just $l$ elements in $Z′\hat{\epsilon}$.

Comment: There are $k-m+l$ elements in $Z^\prime \hat{\boldsymbol\varepsilon}$. For the exogenous variables that are not excluded from the second stage, $x_1, ..., x_{k-m}$,  we have $\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ji }\hat{\varepsilon}_i = 0$ by construction.

Comment: OK, I did not read your matrix dimensions right.

Answer (score 2):

I will give a proof for a general GMM test statistic of overidentifying restrictions, which evaluates the GMM criterion function at the GMM estimate.

The Sargan statistic is a special case of this statistic under conditional homoskedasticity.

The notation and exposition follow Hayashi (2000) Econometrics, so that, unlike in your question, instruments are denoted by $X$ (there are $K$ of them) and regressors by $Z$ (there are $L$ of them). $S_{xz}$ etc. are then corresponding sample moment matrices. $\widehat{\delta}_{GMM}$ is the GMM estimate of the true coefficient $\delta$. $\widehat{S}^{-1}$ is the efficient weighting matrix. $g_i(\tilde{\delta}):=x_{i}(y_i-z_i'\tilde{\delta})$ and $g_n(\tilde{\delta})=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}g_{i}(\tilde{\delta})$

\begin{equation*}
J\bigl(\widehat{\delta}_{GMM},\widehat{S}^{-1}\bigr)\to_d\chi^{2}(K-L).
\end{equation*}

Proof:

First, note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
g_n(\widehat{\delta}_{GMM})&=&s_{xy}-S_{xz}\widehat{\delta}_{GMM}\\
&=&s_{xy}-S_{xz}(S_{xz}'\widehat{S}^{-1}S_{xz})^{-1}S_{xz}'\widehat{S}^{-1}s_{xy}\\
&=&\bigl(I-S_{xz}(S_{xz}'\widehat{S}^{-1}S_{xz})^{-1}S_{xz}'\widehat{S}^{-1}\bigr)s_{xy}\\
&=:&\widehat{B}s_{xy}
\end{eqnarray*}
Further,
\begin{eqnarray}
\widehat{B}s_{xy}&=&(I-S_{xz}(S_{xz}'\widehat{S}^{-1}S_{xz})^{-1}S_{xz}'\widehat{S}^{-1})s_{xy}\notag\\
&=&(I-S_{xz}(S_{xz}'\widehat{S}^{-1}S_{xz})^{-1}S_{xz}'\widehat{S}^{-1})(S_{xz}\delta+g_n(\delta))\notag\\
&=&\underbrace{(S_{xz}-S_{xz}\underbrace{(S_{xz}'\widehat{S}^{-1}S_{xz})^{-1}S_{xz}'\widehat{S}^{-1}S_{xz}}_{I})}_{0}\delta+\widehat{B}g_n(\delta)\notag\\
&=&\widehat{B}g_n(\delta)\label{bgndelta}
\end{eqnarray}

Using the decomposition $\widehat{S}^{-1}=C'C$ we obtain $\widehat{B}'\widehat{S}^{-1}\widehat{B}=(C\widehat{B})'(C\widehat{B})$.
Now,
\begin{eqnarray*}
C\widehat{B}&=&C(I-S_{xz}(S_{xz}'\widehat{S}^{-1}S_{xz})^{-1}S_{xz}'\widehat{S}^{-1})\\
&=&C-CS_{xz}(S_{xz}'C'CS_{xz})^{-1}S_{xz}'C'C\\
&=&C-A(A'A)^{-1}A'C\\
&=&(I-A(A'A)^{-1}A')C\\&=:&MC,
\end{eqnarray*}
where $A:=CS_{xz}$ and, as usual, $M$ is symmetric and idempotent, so that
\begin{equation}\label{Jtestproof3}
\widehat{B}'\widehat{S}^{-1}\widehat{B}=C'M'MC=C'MC.
\end{equation}
Then,
\begin{eqnarray*}
tr(M)&=&tr(I-A(A'A)^{-1}A')\\&=&K-tr((A'A)^{-1}A'A)\\
&=&K-tr(I_L)\\&=&K-L.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, take $D'D=S^{-1}$ so that $C\to_pD$.

With the baseline assumption that, at true value, the sample moment conditions satisfying a CLT, $\sqrt{n}g_n(\delta)\to_dN(0,S)$
it holds that
\begin{eqnarray}
C\sqrt{n}g_n(\delta)&\to_d&N(0,DSD')\notag\\&=&N(0,D(D'D)^{-1}D')\notag
\\&=&N(0,DD^{-1}D'^{-1}D')\notag
\\&=&N(0,I)\label{hansenovern}
\end{eqnarray}
Hence,
\begin{eqnarray}
J\bigl(\widehat{\delta}_{GMM},\widehat{S}^{-1}\bigr)&=&n\cdot g_n(\widehat{\delta}_{GMM})'\widehat{S}^{-1}g_n(\widehat{\delta}_{GMM})\notag\\
&=&n\cdot g_n(\delta)'\widehat{B}'\widehat{S}^{-1}\widehat{B}g_n(\delta)\notag\\
&=&n\cdot g_n(\delta)'C'MCg_n(\delta)\notag\\
&=&\sqrt{n}\cdot(Cg_n(\delta))'M\sqrt{n}Cg_n(\delta)\label{hansenoveridasy}
\end{eqnarray}
Thus, this is asymptotically is a quadratic form in normally distributed vectors and an idempotent matrix $M$ with $tr(M)=rk(M)=K-L$. Thus, (see e.g. Thm. A.87 in Toutenburg and Rao (1999) Linear Models: Least Squares and Alternatives)
$$J\bigl(\widehat{\delta}_{GMM},\widehat{S}^{-1}\bigr)\to_d\chi^{2}(K-L)
$$

Comment: Cheers! I will work through your proof when I get the time. The reference was helpful, found it [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.465.2347&rep=rep1&type=pdf). I'm not sure that it answers my question, though. I'm not saying that it doesn't, either. I'm just not sure yet...

Answer (score 0):

I will use your notation and write $M_A = Id - P_A = Id - A^T (A^T A)^{-1} A$ for the projection onto the orthogonal complement of $A$.
Let's assume all k regressors in $X$ are endogenous, i.e., $k=m$. Otherwise, replace $Z, X, y$ by their projection onto the orthogonal complement of the exogenous regressors. Thus, $\dim(X) = k \leq \dim(Z) = l$.

The J-statistic is

\begin{align*}
J &= \frac{1}{\hat \sigma_\varepsilon^2} (y - X \hat\beta)^T P_Z(y - X\hat\beta).
\end{align*}

Expand

\begin{align*}
P_Z(y - X \hat\beta) &= P_Z\left(X \beta_0 + \varepsilon - X (X^T P_Z X)^{-1} X^T P_Z (X\beta_0 + \varepsilon)\right) \\
&= P_Z \varepsilon - P_Z X (X^T P_Z X)^{-1}X^T P_Z \varepsilon \\
&= P_Z M_{P_Z X} \varepsilon = P_{M_X Z} \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Thus
$$
J = \frac{1}{\hat\sigma_\varepsilon^2} \varepsilon^T P_{M_X Z} \varepsilon.
$$

As $rank(P_{M_X Z}) = l - k$, the result $J \overset{d}{\to} \chi^2(l - k)$ follows from a CLT argument. If the $\varepsilon$ are normal, then $\frac{1}{l - k} J \sim F_{l - k, n - l}$.